# PS3 stuck on 576p

Tags: ps3, monitor, hdmi

I literally tried everything, from changing HDMI cables to changing TVs to resetting the PS3. But the PS3 still is stuck on 576p. Please can anyone suggest any possible way to fix this, it was fine before I don't know what happened to it. I just had a pause of 1 month from gaming and this occurred.

(When I was done resetting the PS3, the message "Mode Not Supported" appeared but it disappeared itself and the PS3 booted at 576p)

I think this is the TV: http://www.samsung.com/au/support/model/PS50C6500TFXXY (Mine was from Singapore)

Also, the HDMI cables I used were the ones that worked previously, and even if I suspect the cables to be faulty, two of them can't be faulty. And two TVs can't be either, so I can't seem to find a solution.

I tried options 2 and 5 from Safe Mode. The PS3 still booted on 576p.

Comment: Do you have possible access to another TV you could try it on? to determine if the console is bugged or the TV is?

Comment: @Rapitor I tried two TVs

Comment: @Rapitor I think its the console which is bugged maybe since I tried on 2 TVs.

Comment: https://www.reddit.com/r/PS3/comments/28ctnv/ps3_stuck_at_576p_resolution_tried_everything/ - Is that the reset you tried?

Answer (score 1):

Go under ps3 settings and instruct it which graphics resolutuions work for your tv it will give you a list from 360p to 1080p that you can check and uncheck;I had a similar problem and this worked for me.

Comment: This didn't fix it sadly, I tried it before (as written in my post). Thanks for your time, really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

You could try resetting the video settings. This usually picks up if there's a different wire to the standard it's setup as.

1. Turn off the PS3
2. Press and hold the power button until you hear two beeps
3. Confirm settings and continue playing your console